# How to generate javadoc for android library when it has dependencies which are also aar libraries?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, javadoc, android-library

I have android library project which depends on other android library projects. I need to generate javadoc for library but it fails because gradle puts to javadoc classpath path to .aar locations but javadoc expects .jar files.

simplified gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    configurations {
        javadocDeps
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.annimon:stream:1.0.7'
    javadocDeps 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.0'
    javadocDeps 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    javadocDeps 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}    

task javadoc(type: Javadoc, dependsOn: explodeAars) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    classpath += configurations.javadocDeps
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}
```

3 solutions possible:

1) somehow to add to the classpath path classes.jar from every aar library it depends build/intermidiates/exploded-aar/library/version/jars/classes.jar
I don't know how to include these paths in javadoc task.

2) manually unpack classes.jar from aar file and add them to classpath of javadoc task

3) very dirty hack - hardcoded paths to library - but I think this is so WRONG.

How to achieve 1 or 2 with gradle dsl?

Comment: Are you using android studio ? There is into Tools > Generate JavaDoc a convenient tool to select what the javadoc needs to take.

Comment: I use android studio but this task must be done automatically on remote jenkins instance. This task used for uploading library to jcenter/mavenCentral

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution from @rve is now broken on Android Studio 2.3 / Gradle 3.3 as the `exploded-aar` no longer exists (with no alternative inside the build directory).

If the aar you depend on is not a module in your project, you will need first to extract the classes.jar before referencing it in the classpath (basically re-create `intermediates/exploded-aar` manually).

If the aar you depend on is just another module in your project you can also make your javadoc task depends on the compile task of that module and reference the `intermediates/classes/release` of that module (if you make javadoc depends on assembleRelease for example). An example of that workaround: https://github.com/Microsoft/mobile-center-sdk-android/pull/345/files

I really wish someone comes up with a better solution though.

Answer (score 7):

I managed to automate the solution of **Guillaume Perrot** by extracting the `classes.jar` contained in each AAR file, and adding it to the classpath of the javadoc task.

It seems to work for AAR dependencies and AAR modules on Android Studio 2.3 and Gradle 3.3

```
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.util.zip.ZipFile

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += configurations.compile
    classpath += configurations.provided

    afterEvaluate {
        // Wait after evaluation to add the android classpath
        // to avoid "buildToolsVersion is not specified" error
        classpath += files(android.getBootClasspath())

        // Process AAR dependencies
        def aarDependencies = classpath.filter { it.name.endsWith('.aar') }
        classpath -= aarDependencies
        aarDependencies.each { aar ->
            // Extract classes.jar from the AAR dependency, and add it to the javadoc classpath
            def outputPath = "$buildDir/tmp/aarJar/${aar.name.replace('.aar', '.jar')}"
            classpath += files(outputPath)

            // Use a task so the actual extraction only happens before the javadoc task is run
            dependsOn task(name: "extract ${aar.name}").doLast {
                extractEntry(aar, 'classes.jar', outputPath)
            }
        }
    }
}

// Utility method to extract only one entry in a zip file
private def extractEntry(archive, entryPath, outputPath) {
    if (!archive.exists()) {
        throw new GradleException("archive $archive not found")
    }

    def zip = new ZipFile(archive)
    zip.entries().each {
        if (it.name == entryPath) {
            def path = Paths.get(outputPath)
            if (!Files.exists(path)) {
                Files.createDirectories(path.getParent())
                Files.copy(zip.getInputStream(it), path)
            }
        }
    }
    zip.close()
}
```

Comment: Great job! This seems to work well for me! Using gradle 3.3.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but I am using the gradle plugin 3.0 in the canary channel (Android Studio 3.0-beta 7). I had to remove the "provided" configuration to get it to compile, but the result is as before - javadoc generation fails because external dependencies are not resolved.

Comment: With com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta7 and hence gradle-4.1, I get several different problems. First of all, some of the java.nio classes are not available, so I rewrote your code without `Paths` and `Files`. Next problem was that the new configurations `api` and `implementation` are not resolvable, so I had to resort to using `compile` dependencies. After doing this it still fails because it cannot find its own R class. After manually adding /build/generated/source/r/debug I got a working javadoc produced. But I really need the new directives to work..

Comment: My tweaked version of @nicopico's code is posted as an alternate answer below. Many thanks for your efforts @nicopico!!

Comment: sadly, this doesn't work with gradle 7.2 and the v26 build tools

Answer (score 4):

**This only works for Android Studio older than 2.3 and/or Gradle older than 3.3**

To add the JARs from the AARs you can add the following `doFirst` to the javadoc task:

```
task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}
.doFirst {
    classpath += fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/intermediates/exploded-aar/", include:"**/classes.jar")
}
```

It will add all `.jar` files from all the AARs to the javadoc classpath. (option 1 from your proposed solutions)

Comment: This is now broken with Android Studio 2.3 / Gradle 3.3. The exploded-aar directory does not exist anymore.

Comment: a side note: this does not work for library projects in with the android gradle plugin 2.3.3

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved this issue, using `zipTree`. Configuration: Gradle 4.10, Gradle Plugin: 3.3.2, Android Studio: 3.4.

```
task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {

    doFirst {
        configurations.implementation
                .filter { it.name.endsWith('.aar') }
        .each { aar ->
            copy {
                from zipTree(aar)
                include "**/classes.jar"
                into "$buildDir/tmp/aarsToJars/${aar.name.replace('.aar', '')}/"
            }
        }
    }

    configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true)
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    classpath += configurations.implementation
    classpath += fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/tmp/aarsToJars/")
    destinationDir = file("${project.buildDir}/outputs/javadoc/")
    failOnError false
    exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
    exclude '**/R.java'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am running the new Android Studio 3.0-beta7, and tried to use @nicopico's answer, but it failed with a number of different errors, so here's an adaptation of it that doesn't rely on the non-existent `java.nio` utilities.

```
task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    failOnError false
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    // Also add the generated R class to avoid errors...
    // TODO: debug is hard-coded
    source += "$buildDir/generated/source/r/debug/"
    // ... but exclude the R classes from the docs
    excludes += "**/R.java"

    // TODO: "compile" is deprecated in Gradle 4.1, 
    // but "implementation" and "api" are not resolvable :(
    classpath += configurations.compile

    afterEvaluate {
        // Wait after evaluation to add the android classpath
        // to avoid "buildToolsVersion is not specified" error
        classpath += files(android.getBootClasspath())

        // Process AAR dependencies
        def aarDependencies = classpath.filter { it.name.endsWith('.aar') }
        classpath -= aarDependencies
        aarDependencies.each { aar ->
            System.out.println("Adding classpath for aar: " + aar.name)
            // Extract classes.jar from the AAR dependency, and add it to the javadoc classpath
            def outputPath = "$buildDir/tmp/exploded-aar/${aar.name.replace('.aar', '.jar')}"
            classpath += files(outputPath)

            // Use a task so the actual extraction only happens before the javadoc task is run
            dependsOn task(name: "extract ${aar.name}").doLast {
                extractEntry(aar, 'classes.jar', outputPath)
            }
        }
    }
}

// Utility method to extract only one entry in a zip file
private def extractEntry(archive, entryPath, outputPath) {
    if (!archive.exists()) {
        throw new GradleException("archive $archive not found")
    }

    def zip = new java.util.zip.ZipFile(archive)

    zip.entries().each {
        if (it.name == entryPath) {
            def path = new File(outputPath)

            if (!path.exists()) {
                path.getParentFile().mkdirs()

                // Surely there's a simpler is->os utility except
                // the one in java.nio.Files? Ah well...
                def buf = new byte[1024]
                def is = zip.getInputStream(it)
                def os = new FileOutputStream(path)
                def len

                while ((len = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
                    os.write(buf, 0, len)
                }
                os.close()
            }
        }
    }
    zip.close()
}
```

It bothers me that we need all this code to produce a freaking javadoc for a library, but at least I got this working. However, I do need to find a workaround for configuration.api and configuration.implementation not being resolvable.

Comment: Separate question asked as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810769/how-to-get-dependencies-from-a-gradle-plugin-using-api-or-implementation-dir

Answer (score 0):

All of the solutions listed here are out of date if you are developing an Android app/library using Kotlin. To generate javadocs as well as documentation in several other formats, use KDoc and Dokka:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-doc.html

https://kotlin.github.io/dokka/1.5.0/

https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka

Answer (score 0):

I posted a solution for this problem at [Android AAR depending on AAR fails with javadoc generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71906540/android-aar-depending-on-aar-fails-with-javadoc-generation/72564890#72564890). I think Johann comment that the listed solutions are out of date is probably correct, but mike192 solution looks pretty good, although I think it might have a problem handling androidx dependencies. I haven't tried KDoc and Dokka yet, but in looking at the documentation, that looks promising. Hopefully it works for android java libraries. The android studio's built-in javadoc tool (2021.2.1) has issues handling that module type; hence the need to build a custom javadoc task to work around those issues.