# Error with Javadoc generation on import android.support.v4.*

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, javadoc

I got error when I generate the javadoc with a gradle task
I create a lib here some part of my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator)) + configurations.compile
    destinationDir = file("../javadoc/")
    exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
    exclude '**/R.java'
    exclude '**/internal/*'
}
```

I get a lot of error like that:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
                             ^
```

I do not understand how to add a link to the support library to my javadoc task.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853906/how-to-generate-javadoc-for-android-library-when-it-has-dependencies-which-are-a The answer from nicopico seems to work