# How to organize common gradle tasks and extract common code blocks

Tags: android, gradle

I have an android project consisting of 10+ library modules. Each of these modules contains a lot of gradle code common to all modules. For example, I'm using the Javadoc generation task from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52286740/1226020) in all of my build.gradle files.

How would I go about to extract that task creation logic to a function put in a separate gradle file which can be "included" by each module? The code is identical for all my modules, but obviously depends on variant and project. Is it possible to extract a function that takes a project as parameter and returns a task for that project?

I'm probably going around this backwards since I really suck at Gradle but any pointers leading to me avoiding having the same 60 lines of gradle code in 10 different files (lib1/build.gradle, lib2/build.gradle, ...) would be helpful!

In fact, taking it even further, basically my entire build.gradle is identical for all projects except the dependencies section - there's an `android` block with `buildTypes`, `compileOptions` etc, there are some plugins applied (`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` etc), and there are some artifact parameters set up. In fact, *only* my dependencies differ at all. So I'm wondering if it would be possible to extract a common file completely, like this (pseudo code obviously):

```
<include common.gradle> // includes android block, common tasks, artifact setup etc. 

dependencies {
  api 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
  api 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract your common settings into a gradle file (lets say `common.gradle` and then use it as

```
apply from: '../path/to/common.gradle'
```

Reference: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:script_plugins

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of extracting common build logic is to [leverage `buildSrc`](https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources) and create plugins that are then applied to your projects.

This has a number of benefits of applying a script, as documented.

In addition, I would recommend being explicit through plugin application. While you could develop a single plugin that configures all your projects, with some logic based on project name for example, it is usually better to have different plugins matching the different project types.
That way, when opening a build file you immediately see what kind of project it is.

And of course you can have common code in `buildSrc` for the common parts.

One more benefit is that moving from a `buildSrc` plugin to a published plugin is much easier ... just in case your configuration patterns start to appear in different projects.