# How to share kotlin multiplatform targets between submodules?

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform, gradle-multi-project-build

After an eternity I managed to setup a kotlin multi-platform and multi-module project. As there is almost no proper guide or documentation, I have just one more issue I couldn't solve.
Can I share kotlin multiplatform targets between the submodules?

Right now every submodule has a `build.gradle.kts` containing:

```
kotlin {
    jvm {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "15"
        }
    }

    js(IR) {
        nodejs()
        browser {
            testTask {
                useKarma {
                    useChromeHeadless()
                    webpackConfig.cssSupport.enabled = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, I want all modules to compile to the same platforms using the same versions and it would be nice to not copy this snippet for every module.
Not to mention that the test dependencies are identical as well.

```
sourceSets {
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.kotest:kotest-framework-api:$kotestVersion")
                implementation("io.kotest:kotest-assertions-core:$kotestVersion")
                implementation("io.kotest:kotest-property:$kotestVersion")
            }
        }

        val jvmTest by getting {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.kotest:kotest-runner-junit5:$kotestVersion")
            }
        }

        val jsTest by getting {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.kotest:kotest-framework-engine:$kotestVersion")
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60334294/how-to-organize-common-gradle-tasks-and-extract-common-code-blocks

This is the usual gradle way to abstract common config/logic - assume it would also work for KMP